# Can we create a multiple filters/drop downs in DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple app. I have got both date and time in a column. So can we create multiple filters/Dropdowns for this column A

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
df <- data.frame(A=c("2018-01-01 06:06:06","2018-01-02 06:06:01"),B=c("A","B"))
DT::dataTableOutput('a')
output$a <- DT::renderDataTable(
    df)
```
````